# image как работает с width 100%, height auto?

Tags: html, css, scss

результат зависит только от ширины. Как могу делать чтобы рисунок должен быть в полном режиме с зависимостью от ширины, кроме высоты

```
<a class="white-link">
  <img src="" alt="" class="image" >
</a>

.white-link {
            font-weight: 700;
            color: $white;
            .image {
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100vw;
                height: auto;
                background-image: url("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/5772b3c08130511f7703baf4/57c1f73c416e239c634e2049_41R0ACPVG5L.jpg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: url("https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/5772b3c08130511f7703baf4/57c1f73c416e239c634e2049_41R0ACPVG5L.jpg");
```

Зачем так делать? `<img>` тег для того и нужен, чтобы в `src` указывать путь:

```
<img src="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/5772b3c08130511f7703baf4/57c1f73c416e239c634e2049_41R0ACPVG5L.jpg">
```

Вот так будет корректно и дать `width:100%; height:auto;`

```css
.white-link {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: $white;
   
    .image {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<a class="white-link">
  <img src="" alt="" class="image" >
</a>
```

Comment: спасибо) за помощью